# HTML5 form validation not working in ASP.NET Web Form

Tags: asp.net, html, validation

I am trying to do a simple project where I can use the required tag on an input field so I can achieve instant form validation. However, I cannot get the validation to trigger. I am using IE11 and Chrome Version 53. Reference: http://www.instantshift.com/2016/05/16/html5-form-validation-floating-input-label/

Site.Master

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">     
      <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>  
<webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" /> 
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="HeadContent" />
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <%--Framework Scripts--%>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
        <%--Site Scripts--%>

    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
<header>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="float-left">
            <p class="site-title">
                <a runat="server" href="~/">your logo here</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="float-right">
            <section id="login">
                <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a id="registerLink" runat="server" href="~/Account/Register.aspx">Register</a></li>
                            <li><a id="loginLink" runat="server" href="~/Account/Login.aspx">Log in</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        <p>
                            Hello, <a runat="server" class="username" href="~/Account/Manage.aspx" title="Manage your account">
                                <asp:LoginName runat="server" CssClass="username" /></a>!
                            <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" />
                        </p>
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </section>
            <nav>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/About.aspx">About</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div id="body">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" />
    <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="MainContent" />
    </section>
</div>
<footer>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="float-left">
            <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
</form>
```

input used in here
Default.aspx

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

    <div>
        <label for="name">Name (required):</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="email">Email (required):</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" required="">
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: May I ask why you are not using `RequiredFieldValidator` control?

Comment: @UmutEsen I believe with the RequiredFieldValidator it only triggers upon postback/ button click correct? I want to instantly show validation without clicking button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an event for validating the inputs regardless of what you use.
The following will work if the user enters a value, removes it and moves away from the input.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtInput" runat="server" CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="form" ControlToValidate="txtInput" ErrorMessage="Please provide a value" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Once you know when to validate the input, use the `Page_IsValid` function to check if the form is in a valid state in javascript.

Please look at the following for validation using HTML5 elements:

```
    <label for="name">Name (required):</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" required="" onblur="validate(this)" runat="server"/>

    <label for="email">Email (required):</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" required="" onblur="validate(this)" runat="server"/>

    <script>

        function validate(input) {
            if (input.value.length === 0) {
                alert("Please provide a value in " + input.name + " input");
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the exact same thing using the input field

Comment: Thanks! THis really helps

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<div>
    <label for="name">Name (required):</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value=""
        required="required" runat="server">
</div>
<div>
    <label for="email">Email (required):</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value=""
        required="required" runat="server">
</div>
```

Comment: No luck on that change

Comment: I have no submit button, my understanding is that I would be able to use instant form validation without having a submit button using HTML5 am I correct?

Comment: Validation cannot happen if you are not submitting the form.

Comment: So my only option is to use javascript for what i want to achieve?

Comment: @IrishChieftain That is not true, the unobtrusive validation package from the ASP.NET team validates instantly without submitting the form (for client-side validation, of course).

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Do you have an example I can use?

Comment: @DeVonte Look here: https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive

Comment: If you are using client-side validation, you also need to do it on the server side. De Vonte, this library only works with the newer Core version?